# ¿como crear dimensión personalizada en google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

este es mi primer mensaje en la comunidad, tengo una duda que espero me podáis ayudar.

La duda en cuestión es con Google Analytics y la forma de crear dimensiones personalizadas. Me adelanto al decir que me lo han encargado y es algo con lo que no he trabajado nunca, por lo que es algo que no controlo en absoluto.

La cuestión es que me han encargado crear una dimensión personalizada para **recoger como variable el ID de Pedido que se recoge en la URL de confirmación de compra** y no tengo ni la más remota idea de como hacerlo.

¿Alguien en la comunidad me podría ayudar?

Muchas gracias!